# What's the word that refers to the pronoun the possessive pronoun his/her relates to?

Tags: grammar, word-request

I don't remember what it's called. For instance:

> Robert lost his keys.

**Robert** is the pronoun the possessive pronoun **his** refers to.

I am guessing there's a technical term used by grammarians, but I have no idea what it is.

If I were to give a stab at it, I would call it the master pronoun, but that sounds just dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be ***[antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar))***. It's fairly technical, yes. There may be other terms for it; there often are.

And *Robert* is a noun, not a pronoun. Pronouns have antecedents; nouns don't.